# center text inside legend CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I center the text inside the legend. I would like to have a fixed width for the legend. When I use `text-align:center;` inside legend, it moves the whole legend box to the center instead of the text inside.

```
 fieldset
    {
        padding: 1px 2px 4px 2px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
 legend
    {
        border: 1px solid gray;
        margin-left: 10px;           
        padding:2px;
        width:150px;           
    }
```

I can center the text by removing width and using:

```
padding: 2px 20px 2px 20px;
```

but then I wouldnt have a fixed width for the legends in the screen. Here's how it looks now-
[image]

Comment: Sorry for missing out a point. I tried text-align already but it was moving the whole legend. @nikhil's answer fixed it. Thank you everyone .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `text-align : center` on `legend`, it would center-align the whole legend.

Instead change your HTML to :

```
<legend><p>Product Details</p></legend>
```

And then use this CSS :

```
legend p {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `text-align: center;` to Center the text inside the legend.

```
legend {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**text-align: center**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

```
legend {
        border: 1px solid gray;
        margin-left: 10px;           
        padding:2px;
        width:150px;  
        text-align: center;  //ADD this to center align the text         
    }
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LnfrX/)
**Updates:**

Since you mentioned it is aligning the entire legend, try this (though not supported in HTML5)

```
<legend><center>Product Details</center></legend>
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LnfrX/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't visualize exactly what you want, but have you use this proprietary :

```
text-align:center
```

You can also put you text in  < span > and place it where you want from the css